# Binomial theorem for differences

Tags: calculus, binomial-theorem

Let $\Delta  x_ {k} = x_{k} - x_{k+1} $ and the convention  $\Delta ^{1} = \Delta$  where $x_ {k}$ is a sequence.

So $\Delta^{2} x_ {k} = \Delta ( \Delta x_{k} ) = \Delta (x_{k} -x_{k+1}) $
$= x_{k} - x_{k+1} -(x_{k+1} -x_{k+2}) = x_{k} -2x_{k+1} + x_{k+2}$.

Argue that the $\Delta$ function is linear for addition and prove

$\Delta^{k} a_{m} = \sum_{j =0}^k (-1)^{j}  \binom{k}{j}  x_{j} $
where $a_{m}$ is the arithmetic mean.

I guess the best and easiest way to prove this is by induction but I can't see how to do it.

The theorem is from this paper where the argument is too unclear for me. 
Page 20/63
http://www.cs.umb.edu/~offner/files/pi.pdf

Comment: What is $x_k$? What is $a_m$? Should "factorial" be "binomial"?

Comment: $x_{k}$ is simply a sequence and factorial means the binomial coefficient.

Comment: And what is $a_m$?

Comment: The arithmetic mean.

Comment: Please edit your question.